# Delphi: A generic list of generic-descendants and taking a generic as a parameter

Tags: delphi, generics, delphi-2010

I struggle a little with the understanding of generics and how they can and can not be used.

I have a generic class TControlMediator like this:

```
TControlMediator<C, T> = class
private
  FMediatedComponent: C;
public
  constructor Create(ComponentToMediate: C);

  function GetValue: T; virtual; abstract;
  procedure SetValue(Value: T); virtual; abstract;

  property MediatedControl: C read FMediatedComponent;
end;
```

I then make 'concret' subclasses for each control type that I want to mediate:

```
TEditMediator = class(TControlMediator<TEdit, string>)
public
  function GetValue: string; override;
  procedure SetValue(Value: string); override;
end;
```

So far, everything seems to work OK. Problems arise, though, when I want a list of TControlMediator descendants, or taking a TControlMediator as an parameter to a method:

```
TViewMediator = class
private
  FControlMediators: TList<TControlMEdiator<C, T>>;
public
  procedure registerMediator(AControlMediator: TControlMediator<C, T>);
  procedure unregisterMediator(AControlMediator: TControlMediator<C, T>);
end;
```

The compiler stops with fatal errors:

```
[DCC Error] mediator.pas(23): E2003 Undeclared identifier: 'C'
[DCC Error] mediator.pas(28): E2007 Constant or type identifier expected
```

Do anybody have any clues on how this is supposed to be done?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Delphi has no covariance or contravariance on its generic types. Your generic types must use actual types as parameters. In other words, this:

```
TViewMediator = class
private
  FControlMediators: TList<TControlMEdiator<C, T>>;
public
  procedure registerMediator(AControlMediator: TControlMediator<C, T>);
  procedure unregisterMediator(AControlMediator: TControlMediator<C, T>);
end;
```

...won't work because C and T are not generic type arguments to `TViewMediator` or actual types.

`TControlMediator<TEdit, string>` is a type. `TList<TControlMEdiator<C, T>>`, when there are no types `C` or `T` in scope is not a type. You can't use a generic type placeholder in an *instantiation* of a generic type unless those placeholders are in scope as generic arguments to the containing generic type or method.

Comment: So I'm basically screwed, then? My list has to be a good old TList of TObjects, and there is no way of casting the objects in it to an TControlMediator<C, T> so that I can call methods on it?

Comment: I can't say if you're screwed until I understand exactly why you want to do this. Could you just parameterize as `TViewMediator<C, T>` ?

Comment: I want to register mediators of different kind like:

  MyViewMediator.RegisterMediator(TEditMediator.create(someEdit));
  MyViewMediator.RegisterMediator(TComboMediator.create(someCombo));

Later, I want to loop all registered mediators and call a method on them.

Comment: You can give your generic type a non-generic parent type, and make your list a list of that.

Comment: Yes, that's the solution that I have come to. Maybe even an interface.

Comment: Mmmm, but what if best parent class would be TList<T> ? Then that makes one screwed.

Okay, i may make one wrapper class TDummy, then make few children *TDummy<T: record> = class(TDummy) public Storage:TList<T>; end;* Well, that seems pointless, i still cannot make generic subroutines over collection of TDummy...

Comment: In effect i want to make generic disc scanner with number of engines that may or may not turn TFileName -> some-record, then make them stored into collections, then make those collections saved into report.  Ideally that engine would not get coupled to backend store. So i can easily make all separate enmgines and up to TList<T> they produce. But then i'd like to have some decoupled saving class/routine, that would get collection of results and save them. Ideally there should be a registry like TDictionary<> record-type -> engine-class. Or even better a number of storage back-ends.

Comment: I can make backend have generic method like *public Save<T: record>(const Ts: TEnumerable<T>)* but still how would i be able to make a registry of such collections? If not to resort to one super-object having them all...