# Delphi generics: How to spec "class that references its own type"

Tags: delphi, generics, collections, copy

In Delphi XE2, I want to write a generic collection class which manipulates objects which must have a Copy(owntype) method, but I can't figure out how best to declare this.

I want something like this example (a collection of one item, for simplicity):

```
//------ Library ------
Type
  TBaseCopyable = class
    S: string;
//    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TBaseCopyable); overload;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TBaseCopyable); virtual;
  end;

  MyCollection<T: TBaseCopyable, constructor> = class
    TheItem: T;
    procedure SetItem(AItem: T); 
    function  GetItem: T;
  end;

[...]

function MyCollection<T>.GetItem: T;
Var
  NewItem: T;
begin
  NewItem := T.Create;
  NewItem.Copy(TheItem);
  Result := NewItem;
end;


//------ Usage ------
Type
  TMyCopyable = class(TBaseCopyable)
    I: integer;
//  procedure Copy(OtherObject: TMyCopyable); overload;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TMyCopyable); override;
  end;

[...]
  Col: MyCollection<TMyCopyable>;
```

The key problem is that in Col, I need the generic implementation of MyCollection to find TMyCopyable.Copy. Unsurprisingly, neither overload or virtual do the job:

- With overload, the code compiles, but MyCollection.GetItem finds
  TBaseCopyable.Copy, not TMyCopyable.Copy.
- With virtual/override this
  doesn't compile because the signatures of the two Copy declarations
  don't match.

So I figure I need to use generics somehow in the specification of TBaseCopyable, possibly instead of inheritance. But I'm not sure how, primarily because I don't particularly need  to feed a type parameter into TBaseCopyable, I just need the Copy argument type to refer to "the type of it's own class" in a generic way.

Ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Your GetItem looks like it's going to encourage leaks.

Comment: Don't worry, it's just a contrived example to test which Copy will be invoked.

Comment: Related question: "A generic list of generic-descendants and taking a generic as a parameter" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1632884/delphi-a-generic-list-of-generic-descendants-and-taking-a-generic-as-a-paramete

Answer (score 6):

Turn `TBaseCopyable` into a Generic class and apply its Generic type to `Copy()`, then `TMyCopyable` can override it, eg:

```
type
  TBaseCopyable<T> = class
    S: string;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: T); virtual;
  end;

  MyCollection<T: TBaseCopyable<T>, constructor> = class
    TheItem: T;
    procedure SetItem(AItem: T);
    function  GetItem: T;
  end;
```

```
type
  TMyCopyable = class(TBaseCopyable<TMyCopyable>)
    I: integer;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TMyCopyable); override;
  end;
```

Alternatively, just do the same thing that `TPersistent.Assign()` does (since it does not use Generics):

```
type
  TBaseCopyable = class
    S: string;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TBaseCopyable); virtual;
  end;

  MyCollection<T: TBaseCopyable, constructor> = class
    TheItem: T;
    procedure SetItem(AItem: T);
    function  GetItem: T;
  end;
```

```
type
  TMyCopyable = class(TBaseCopyable)
    I: integer;
    procedure Copy(OtherObject: TBaseCopyable); override;
  end;

procedure TMyCopyable.Copy(OtherObject: TBaseCopyable);
begin
  inherited;
  if OtherObject is TMyCopyable then
    I := TMyCopyable(OtherObject).I;
end;
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks! Not sure I would have discovered that generic syntax, though it makes sense now that I see it, of course. And preferable to the non-generic version, as in the non-generic version the compiler doesn't enforce OtherObject to be the desired type.

Comment: Unfortunately, in testing, Remy's generic version doesn't quite do the job, and as yet I'm not sure how to proceed. The issue is that TBaseCopyable<T>.Copy(OtherObject: T)  can't access members of OtherObject (for example S, or other methods of there are some), because it's type T and not type TBaseCopyable<T>. But if we declare OtherObject to be TBaseCopyable<T>, then descendants can't override it with a different argument type. I think. At the moment I'm short of a super clarifying example.

Comment: Also, I'm troubled by "MyCollection<T: TBaseCopyable<T>"... what do the two "T"s refer to? Different types or the same type. The compiler swallows it, but not sure what it means.

Comment: Two T's refer to the same type. If you want different types use different capitals.

Comment: @gwideman: of course you can access members of `OtherObject` from with `TBaseCopyable<T>.Copy`, but, also of course, only public members or public and protected members if T itself is descendant from `TBaseCopyable<T>`. That said, each inheritance level should only copy the members it declared itself. `TBaseCopyable<T>` should only copy its own members, and shouldn't need access to OtherObject's private members. Descendants can override it with a different type, provided they all ultimately have `TBaseCopyable<T>` as their ancestor. Unless, you want to mix types in a single collection.

Comment: @gwideman: have a look at how `TPersistent.Assign` works, both in `TPersistent` itself and in `TPersistent` descendants. Also, if you want to have various descendants of TBaseCopyable<T> in a single collection, you should study up on covariance and contravariance. Slightly mind boggling when you are new to generics, but you are gonna need it.

Comment: @gwideman: yeah, I started noticing the same problems after I posted my initial answer, that is why I added the non-Generic alternative as a fallback.  I don't have a solution yet.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question, or at least summarizing findings:

So far as I can tell, there is no complete answer to the question as I posed it. What I have learned is this:

[1] Remy's solution is the way to go if the base item class (here TBaseCopyable) has no state, and either is abstract, or methods don't need to refer to other objects of the same type. (Eg: TBaseCopyable would have no fields and only abstract methods.)

[2] A significant issue is how to specify a generic class whose *descendant* classes can specify method arguments and return values of the same type as their enclosing class.  In Remy's example, that is accomplished in the descendant class declaration:

```
      TMyCopyable = class(TBaseCopyable<TMyCopyable>)
```

This means that in the generic class, T will be replaced by the ultimate class of interest.

[3] However, within TBaseCopyable's generic declaration, the information that T is always a TBaseCopyable is not available, so in TBaseCopyable's implementation, references to objects of type T won't be able to see TBaseCopyable's methods or fields.

This would be solved if we could set a constraint on T to tell the compiler that T is a TBaseCopyable.

That's apparently the approach in C#: 
 http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/03/curiouser-and-curiouser.aspx

In Delphi, I think that would go like this:

```
  type
    TBaseCopyable<T: TBaseCopyable<T> > = class
    ...
```

like Remy shows for MyCollection. However, that syntax is not legal within the same class declaration (error: undeclared identifier TBaseCopyable), because TBaseCopyable is not yet fully defined. We might think to create a forward declaration for TBaseCopyable (like we would for non-generic classes), but that throws an error, and apparently it's not supported by the compiler:

- [How to set a forward declaration with generic types under Delphi 2010?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6055742/how-to-set-a-forward-declaration-with-generic-types-under-delphi-2010)
- E2086 error with forward declaration of a generic type http://qc.embarcadero.com/wc/qcmain.aspx?d=94044

[4] Maybe the generic class could inherit the implementation?

What if we did this:

```
  type
    TBaseCopyable<T> = class(TBaseCopyableImpl) ...
```

That would allow TBaseCopyable to have some fields and methods that could refer to each other. However, even if those methods were virtual, they would impose fixed argument/return types on the descendants, the avoidance of which was the rationale for using generics in the first place.

So this strategy is only good for fields and methods that don't need to specialize in the descendant types... for example an object counter.

Conclusions

This question turns out to concern the somewhat-known "Curiously recurring template pattern": http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern. Even though it seems what one is trying to accomplish is simple, there are theoretical problems behind the scenes.

The situation appears to call for a language keyword meaning something like "Same type as my enclosing class". However that apparently leads to covariance/contravariance issues -- violations of the rules of which types can substitute for which in inheritance hierachies.  That said, it seems Delphi doesn't go as far as C# to permit as much of a partial solution.

Of course, I'd be happy to learn that there is a way to go further!

Oh, and I don't feel too bad struggling to get to the bottom of this -- even Ken Arnold thinks it's difficult: https://weblogs.java.net/blog/arnold/archive/2005/06/generics_consid.html#comment-828994

:-)

Comment: Note that [QualityCentral has now been shut down](https://community.embarcadero.com/blogs/entry/quality-keeps-moving-forward), so you can't access `qc.embarcadero.com` links anymore. If you need access to old QC data, look at [QCScraper](http://www.uweraabe.de/Blog/2017/06/09/how-to-save-qualitycentral/).